# HDInsight query console Job History

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I am new to Microsoft Azure. I created a trial account on Azure. Installed the azure powershell and submitted the default wordcount map reduce program and it works fine and am able to see the results in the powershell. Now when I open the query console of my cluster in the HDInsight tab, the job history is empty. What am I missing here? Where can I view the job results in the Azure?

Answer (score 1):

The Query Console does not display M/R jobs, only hive jobs.  You can see the history of all jobs by using the PowerShell cmdlet for [get-azurehdinsightjob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593752.aspx) while will return all of these.

Answer (score 0):

The query console is designed to submit/monitor Hive jobs, so I think it only shows job history for Hive jobs. You can see the job result using HDInsight Powershell SDK though. The

Comment: Thanks for the reply..Could you point me to any example or reference doc which uses the Powershell SDK to display the job results. Also my code is in Java,do they have a Java SDK?

Comment: You can find lots of Azure SDK projects at: https://github.com/azure/  The Java SDK does not look like it supports HDInsight, but the [node.js sdk](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node) does.  Alternately is is possible to query directly against the Templeton endpoint like in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/04/22/querying-hdinsight-job-status-with-webhcat-via-native-powershell-or-node-js.aspx  If you can make REST calls and parse json responses, you should be able to get job status from your cluster.