# HDInsight SparkHistory on Azure shows no applications

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I have created a **Spark HDInsight Cluster** on **Azure**. The cluster was used to run different jobs (either Spark or Hive).

Until a month ago, the history of the jobs could be seen in the **Spark History Server dashboard**. It seems that following the update that introduced Spark 1.6.0, this dashboard is no longer showing any applications.

I have also tried to bypass this issue by executing the PowerShell cmdlet for **get-azurehdinsightjob** as sugested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633778/hdinsight-query-console-job-history%20this%20link.). The output is again an empty list of applications.

I would appreciate any help as this dashboard used to work and now all my experiments are stalled.

Comment: Check if your application or shell are connected to the correct master.

Comment: Yes, the shell is properly connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by **deleting** everything inside **wasb:///hdp/spark-events**. Maybe the issue was related to the size of the folder, as no other log files could be appended.

All the following jobs are now appearing successfully in the Spark History Server dashboard.